# How to pass user-defined table type into cursor as parameter?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to input a package defined table type as a parameter into a cursor and join it as table, but apparently it differs from using database defined table types. The following example works with database defined table types.

Taking into example the following package body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY MY_PACK AS
/*******************
    TYPES
********************/
TYPE A_TYPE IS RECORD(
    ID          NUMBER(20),
    CHECK_DATE  DATE
);
TYPE A_TABLE_TYPE IS TABLE OF TYPE A_TYPE BY VARCHAR2(2000);

CURSOR CUR1... -- Does what it does.

CURSOR CUR2(C_TABLE A_TABLE_TYPE)
IS
-- PROBLEM **************************************
  SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE(C_TABLE);

PROCEDURE PROC1 (....)
IS
  l_table      A_TABLE_TYPE;
  l_rec        A_TYPE;
BEGIN
    FOR RES IN CUR1(...)
    LOOP
        IF NOT l_table.EXISTS(RES.ID) THEN
            l_rec.ID := RES.ID;
            l_rec.CHECK_DATE := RES.DATE;
            l_table(RES.ID) := l_rec;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- ************** PROBLEM ****************************************
    FOR RES2 IN CUR2(C_TABLE => l_table)
    LOOP
        -- DOO
    END LOOP;
END PROC1;
```

EXAMPLE FROM COMMENT:

```
CURSOR CUR2(C_TABLE A_TABLE_TYPE) 
IS
  SELECT *
  FROM
    (SELECT ID FROM TABLE(C_TABLE) ) AS FILTER,
    DB_TABLE
  WHERE DB_TABLE.ID = FILTER.ID;
```

Comment: It's hard to tell how much you've simplified this; if you're just selecting everything from the table then why not just loop over the collection directly? And if you're really joining that to another table are you just using the ID field?

Comment: I think *PLS-00642: local collection types not allowed in SQL statements* is going to be the problem.

Comment: Why do you want a cursor with a collection as parameter? you can iterate like this `for rec in 1 ..l_table.count loop ... end loop;`

Comment: @hotfix It is a matter of optimization i don't want to loop throught it because the query is very heavy in that cursor (pluss it has instructions for the optimiser). So, i am passing my table type variable into the cursor and then i join it with the result from the query in the cursor.
`CURSOR CUR2(C_TABLE A_TABLE_TYPE)
IS
  SELECT * 
  FROM
    (SELECT ID FROM TABLE(C_TABLE) ) AS FILTER
    DB_TABLE
  WHERE DB_TABLE.ID = FILTER.ID;
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

**Alternative 1:**
you can try to use an explicit Cursor in your Loop

```
for rec in (SELECT *
              FROM
                (SELECT ID FROM TABLE(l_table) ) AS FILTER,
                DB_TABLE
              WHERE DB_TABLE.ID = FILTER.ID
           )
loop
...
end loop;
```

**Alternative 2:**

you do a 1 cursor by joining select from cur1 with a select from cur2

**Alternative 3:**

Instead of the record in the package, I suggest working with Oralce types.
You create an object type and a table type

```
create or replace type a_type as object 
( 
    ID          NUMBER(20),
    CHECK_DATE  DATE

)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE a_type_tab IS TABLE OF a_type ;
/
```

in the cursor you can then use this type as a parameter

```
CURSOR CUR2(t a_type_tab)
IS
  SELECT * 
  FROM TABLE(t);
```

In the procedure, you can easily fill this type and pass it to your cursor

```
procedure test as

    tab a_type_tab;
  begin
    tab := a_type_tab();
    for rec in cur1 loop

      tab.EXTEND();
      tab(tab.last) := a_type(rec.id,rec.dat);

    end loop;

    for rec2 in cur2(tab) loop
       dbms_output.put_line(rec2.id);
    end loop;
  end test;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that in a different way, that i wont have to define these types in schema level ?

Comment: @KALALEX can you use an implicit cursor in your loop or do you need a global explicit cursor?